# Cannot change the order of pokemon when battling a gym

Tags: pokemon-go

When I (Lvl 35) battle a gym (non-Raid), it won't let me change my pokemon. (I can change if it is a RAID battle for some reason.) If I do exchange even one pokemon, then the BATTLE button goes dark. It's annoying but I can defeat most pokemon with the ones I am given EXCEPT Blisseys. The AI never chooses my fighting types and so I run out of time, even with low level Blisseys. I even battle the Blissey several times to damage my pokemon so they won't be chosen the next time, but the AI still refuses to put my powerful Machamp in the lineup, thinking Jolteons are better. It is to the point now, that if I see a Blissey, I don't even bother trying. Someone please help me.

Comment: This sounds like a bug, have you reported it?